# Soldering generic AC/DC to 4 pin plug

Tags: soldering, pins, ac-dc

So, long story short: I'll soon have a PCB which accepts 24v 5a power input and has a 4 pin power plug of this type:

[image: 4 pin power plug]

And is wired like this:

[image: 4 pin wiring]

My question is: assuming I have a generic AC/DC adapter with the correct voltage and amperage and I cut its plug, if I were to solder its wires on the 4 pin input of the PCB, would it be fine if I soldered the positive wire to both the positive pins and the negative one to both the negative pins? If not, what would be the correct approach?

Comment: Assuming that those are all power pins (and you ohm them out properly, and solder them properly), then yes.

Comment: Yes, all of the four pins are indeed power pins. What exactly do you mean by "ohm them out properly"?

Comment: @Wyse -- as in connect the correct wires to the correct pins

Comment: Just looking at the picture I would expect P2 and P4 to be different voltages... otherwise why bother with this arrangement?

Comment: @Spoon That's what I thought, but I don't own the required power brick so I can't really test the voltages of each pin myself, I only know the total output voltage. I guess I should ask a seller for the voltages of each pin just to be sure.

Comment: Here are the final results: in my case both the pins have the same voltage, so soldering the positive wire to both the positive pins and the negative wire to both the negative pins worked out fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly how it is done. As long as you meet the required specs and properly solder on to the wires,  it should work.